# radomize ul tag not working

Tags: javascript, html

this is probably an easy question for you guys but I'm very new to coding and can't figure out this. I have a code that I want to randomize the given choices in the questions, and I've found a script online that does that but it's not working. I don't know what the

```
// shuffle only elements that don't have "group" class
$ul.find("li[class!='single_question', 'question', 'title', 'text']").each(function() {
```

means so I tried to put all id that I don't need to randomize in it but it's still not working. 
 Can someone help me this please? Also is there anyway I can add choice "A", choice "B", choice "C", and choice "D" in front of each given options so even after the options(answers) are randomized, the A,B,C,D options will still be in order? Thank you. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="JQ.js"></script>
<script src="function.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div id="quiz_container">
      <ul class="quiz_container">
        <li class="single_question" data-question-id="1" data-correct-answer="1">
          <div class="question">
            <h1 class="title">P.1 Grammar Review</h1>
            <p class="text">1. "What is your name__"</p>
          </div>
          <ul class="options">
            <li value="1">?</li>
            <li value="2">.</li>
            <li value="3">,</li>
          </ul>
          <div class="result"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="single_question" data-question-id="2" data-correct-answer="b">
          <div class="question">
            <p class="text">2. "Do you like the banana__"</p>
          </div>
          <ul class="options">
            <li value="a">.</li>
            <li value="b">?</li>
            <li value="c">,</li>
          </ul>
          <div class="result"></div>
        </li>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     /*
      * shuffles the array
      * @param {Array} myArray array to shuffle
      */
     function shuffleArray(myArray) {
         for (var i = myArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
             var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
             var temp = myArray[i];
             myArray[i] = myArray[j];
             myArray[j] = temp;
         }

         return myArray;
     }

     var $ul, $li, li_content, li_list;

     // find all lists to shuffle
     $("#quiz_container > ul").each(function () {
         $ul = $(this);
         li_list = [];

         // shuffle only elements that don't have "group" class
         $ul.find("li[class!='single_question', 'question', 'title', 'text']").each(function () {
             // add content to the array and remove item from the DOM
             li_list.push($(this).html());
             $(this).remove();
         });

         // shuffle the list
         li_list = shuffleArray(li_list);
         while (li_content = li_list.pop()) {
             // create <li> element and put it back to the DOM
             $li = $("<li />").html(li_content);
             $ul.append($li);
         }
     });

     $("#contact_div").show();
 });

 $(document).on('click', '.single_question .options li', function () {
     // Save the question of the clicked option 
     question = $(this).parents('.single_question');

     // Remove If Anyother option is already selected
     question.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');

     // Add selected class to the clicked li
     $(this).addClass('selected');

     // selected option value
     selected_answer_value = $(this).attr("value");

     // Value of correct answer from '.single-question' attribute
     correct_answer_value = question.attr("data-correct-answer");
     correct_answer_text = question.find('.options').find("li[value='" + correct_answer_value + "']").text();

     if (correct_answer_value == selected_answer_value)
         result = "<div class='correct'> Correct ! </div>";
     else
         result = "<div class='wrong'> Correct answer is -> " + correct_answer_text + "</div>";

     // Write the result of the question
     $(this).parents('.single_question').find('.result').html(result);

     // Calculate the score
     score_calculator();
 });

 /**
  * It loops through every question and increments the value when "data-correct-answer" value and "option's value" are same
  */
 function score_calculator() {
     score = 0;

     $('.single_question').each(function () {
         question = $(this);
         if (question.attr('data-correct-answer') == question.find('.selected').attr("value")) {
             score++;
         }
     });

     $('.correct_answers').html(score);
 }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: `li[class!='single_question', 'question', 'title', 'text']` is not a valid selector

Comment: The markup is invalid. The [`<link>` element has to be in the `<head>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-LINK). And the `ul.quiz_container` is [missing it's end tag `</ul>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using jQuery, even though the question isn't tagged as such. If that's the case, you can use a code snippet written by Chris Coyier of CSS-Tricks called [shuffle children](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/shuffle-children/).

Here's an example of the code in action.

```js
$.fn.shuffleChildren = function() {
    $.each(this.get(), function(index, el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        var $find = $el.children();

        $find.sort(function() {
            return 0.5 - Math.random();
        });

        $el.empty();
        $find.appendTo($el);
    });
};

$("ul.randomized").shuffleChildren();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4>Static List:</h4>
<ul>
  <li>First element</li>
  <li>Second element</li>
  <li>Third element</li>
  <li>Fourth element</li>
</ul>

<h4>Randomized List:</h4>
<ul class="randomized">
  <li>First element</li>
  <li>Second element</li>
  <li>Third element</li>
  <li>Fourth element</li>
</ul>
```

In order to apply it to your own code, all you'd need to do is modify the CSS selector at the bottom of the jQuery snippet. In your case, `ul.options` might be a good choice.

Here are a couple of examples using your markup:

- [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w01onouL/)
- [Self-Contained HTML Doc](https://gist.github.com/woodrowbarlow/30863ba79bc43b091fff7ebbc959b82e)

Comment: Sorry maybe it's a stupid question but I still couldn't figure this out. I changed the $("ul.randomized").shuffleChildren(); to ul.options and then put the function code in my JS file and then put it as <script src="function.js"></script>  in my html script. And copy and save the jquery script and then put in as <script src="jquery.js"></script> in the HTML file as well. But it's still not working...

Comment: [here is a working jsfiddle using your markup](https://jsfiddle.net/w01onouL/) (i fixed some invalid markup in there), and [here it is in a full self-contained HTML document](https://gist.github.com/woodrowbarlow/30863ba79bc43b091fff7ebbc959b82e).